# Is it possible to change all row values in one instruction?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv("PastHires.csv")
```

I have the "Hired" column that has Y/N values. I'd like to make them 1 or 0 to plot them. 
Is it possible to achieve something like this?

```
df['Hired'] = 1 if df['Hired'] is 'Y' else 0
```

at the moment it puts 0 to all rows :(

edit:
Fixed according to 0x2bad answer:

```
dist = df[['Previous employers','Hired']][4:10]
dist['Hired'] = 1 if dist['Hired'] == 'Y' else 0
```

but throws "the truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Hired'] = pd.np.where(df.Hired == 'Y', 1, 0)
```

Or [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Hired'] = df.Hired.map({'Y': 1, 'N', 0})
```

Which is less efficient, but can handle more than two cases.

Note than these will be faster than`apply` on 1000+ rows.

Comment: This is the best answer, using vectorized solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `apply` method, [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply), which can be used to run a function for each value in the Series.

In your case, using an anonymous function...

```
df['Hired'] = df['Hired'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'Y' else 0)
```

... where `x` is each value in the Series.

Answer (score 1):

More like

```
df['Hired'] = df.Hired.eq('Y').astype(int)
```